# Wildcard CSS Selector That Can Detect A Class Inside Same Class

Tags: css, wildcard

I am creating a dynamic navigation list and I want to be able to highlight the page from that list that the user is currently browsing without having to explicitly add the style into a CSS document. For instance,

```
<div class="check-me">
    <ul class="any-class">
        <li class="hats">Hats</li>
        <li class="shirts">Shirts</li>
        <li class="pants">Pants</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Essentially, I want to be able to replace the "any-class" with another class, one that appears on an LI element within the "any-class" UL.

```
<div class="check-me">
    <ul class="shirts">
        <li class="hats">Hats</li>
        <li class="shirts">Shirts</li>
        <li class="pants">Pants</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I cannot append an "active" class to any LI due to limitations, so I wonder if this is possible using a wildcard CSS selector to use inside div.check-me to highlight anything that shares the same class with the UL. I hope I've been clear enough.

Comment: Raw CSS doesn't have any variables or back-references, so I don't think you can do this. Maybe use a preprocessor like LESS?

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you for taking the time to answer, Barmar. I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything in the current CSS specifications. I'll have to build a passable hook for this then, trying not to use JS if possible.